# Record Sound in Cocoa Example Please!

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-audio, audioqueueservices, qtkit

I've been scouring both this site and the net in general for an example cocoa app that uses QTKit or Audio Queue and actually works.

Unfortunately, I can't find anything that fits the above description.

All I want to do is get a simple audio recording app so I can learn how it works!

Please, I have put alot of time into this already so don't point me to Apple Dev. It is just too dense for my simple brain.

And yes, there is a dupe or two here, but none of them actually produced a satisfactory outcome.

I am desperate! I feel like this should be WAY easier. I am starting to worry about getting deeply into Cocoa because the developer documentation is really not good.

Help!

Comment: If I can get something working, I'll put up a screencast!!! I promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not reasonable to ask people not to point to the documentation, especially when there is [a step-by-step tutorial for creating a simple recording app with QTKit therein](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/UsingQTKit/UsingQTKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008156-CH108-SW29). It's titled "Creating a Simple Capture and Recording Application" with about ten steps (with code).  If that's not enough, the Sample Code section gives you "[MyRecorder](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/MYRecorder/Introduction/Intro.html)," which is a ready-to-go media recorder using QTKit.

It's far easier to get help if you a) don't limit people by telling them not to refer you to a resource and, b) start with some standard resource and explain what it is that's confusing you or that's not working for you, so we have a starting point from which to offer help.

Comment: Yes, where ARE my manners. In the end, I did find some sample code from the Pragmatic Bookshelf that did just the trick. Luckily, they are far more forgiving regarding learners such as myself, but thank you for taking the time. It was helpful.

Comment: Hi Alec, can you give me the link to that sample code or tell me the name of the project/book? I am looking for the exact same thing and have been fooling around with QTKit for 2 days with no luck.